# Solver Looping in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I have a worksheet where we need to solve the "incoming" values for each period.

[image]

[image]

Here each period has a beginning balance, which is carried over from the ending balance from the previous period, and an expected outgoing. I want to solve the incomings so that the ending balances are kept at a minimum while staying above the minimum requirements (based on the expected outgoings for future periods). The incomings also need to be non-negative.

Here's the VBA code I wrote but when I ran it, it took a good minute to solve 12 values. Being new to Excel VBA, I'm scratching my head having no idea if there's something wrong with how I structure the code or that's just how the solver performs. Can anyone enlighten me? If I have 50 periods to solve for each of the 100 scenarios, is it the most efficient way to run solver?

My other question is the grid I have is in the "Long" format as each time period is stacked on top of one another. If I have it transposed to a "wide" format, is there a way I can reference the range elegantly?

Thank you!

```
Dim i_ As Integer

Worksheets("sheet2").Activate

For i_ = 3 To 14

    SolverReset
    
    SolverOK SetCell:="$E" & i_, MaxMinVal:=2, ByChange:="$D" & i_
    Solveradd CellRef:=Range("E" & i_), relation:=3, formulatext:=Range("F" & i_)
    Solveradd CellRef:=Range("d" & i_), relation:=3, formulatext:=0
    
    Solversolve True
    
    Next i_
    
End Sub
```

Comment: As far as I understood, putting a simple formula will do the job: `Incoming = Ending Bal - Beginning Bal + Outgouing`

Comment: It causes a circular reference error.

Comment: Then, I think, my abovementioned formula can be solved in VBA and results put in respective cells.